# Excel Macro to pick values from one table/array to another

Tags: excel, copy, row, element, vba

I have the following "table" in an Excel sheet. I would like to do the following change:

Each time when there is a "x" I would like to report on another sheet the corresponding value of the first row and corresponding value of the first column:

"Original Table"

```
    a1      a2      a3      a7      a8      a9
    main    main    main    main    main    main
u1  X       X        X
u2          X        X
u3                      
u4                      
u5  X           
u6                   X
```

"Transformed Table":

```
  u1 a1
  u1 a2
  u1 a3
  u2 a2
  u2 a3
  u5 a1
  u6 a3
```

Could you please tell me what is the Excel macro that will do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "The Excel macro that will do this" will be whichever one you write to do it.  What have you done so far, and what problems are you encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that sheet(2) exists (ie doesn't check).  It will populate sheet(2) with the row and column headers as you've given in your example:

```
Sub ReportOnAllXs()
  Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, r2 As Integer
  r2 = 1
  With Sheets(1)
    For r = 3 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
      For c = 2 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If .Cells(r, c).Value = "X" Then
          Sheets(2).Cells(r2, 1).Value = .Cells(r, 1).Value
          Sheets(2).Cells(r2, 2).Value = .Cells(1, c).Value
          r2 = r2 + 1
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

I'm also assuming that you want the resulting row and column values in separate cells on sheet(2).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is Excel VBA question and it cannot be done with built-in formulae. In Google Sheets, you can do achieve this with built-in functions only. When 'a1' is on `B1` and 'u1' is on `A3`, you can get the table with just one formula. Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L0YZGyqU9_sVHngmPhj9w7c-d1UWhE2ssZmNevPqq-I/).

```
=transpose(
  split(
   concatenate(
    arrayformula(
     if(B3:G8="x", "u"&(row(B3:G8)-row($A$3)+1)&" a"&(column(B3:G8)-column($B$1)+1)&char(10), "")
    )
   ), char(10)
  )
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot ! If I need Google Sheets i will know how to use it.